How to add delay between two trades
How can I add delay of 10 seconds between exitLongCondition and shortCondition and vice versa.
if (exitLongCondition)
strategy.close("Long")

if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if (exitShortCondition)
strategy.close("Short")

if (longCondition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

I tried many combination but it is not working, hence I need help.

This question is similar to: Delayed trade reentry. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  OR How to force a waiting time of a few seconds between execution of commands in Pine?

What version of PineScript are you using?

try this:
if exitLongCondition and (timenow-time) >= 10000


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
